# In the VS2013 Merge Wizard, how do I remove entries in the Target Branch dropdown?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, merge

When I am merging with another branch in Visual Studio 2013's Source Control Merge Wizard, I am confronted with the following dialogue:
[image: dialogue example]
In the Target Branch, there are 2 entries, one from a branch I had used a while ago, but I no longer use, and the one I actually use.  The one I don't use is the default, and it is quite annoying that it is there.

I want to remove the no longer used entry.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The target branch will list the parent and the children of the current branch. If the branch you want to remove is a child branch, you can simply delete it (disclaimers about deleting branches here).

Comment: `disclaimers about deleting branches here` Where?  In any case, can I get rid of it without deleting the branch?  How is the default selected? Can I at least pick the default?

Comment: It was my attempt at humor. What I meant was that you are deleting things so be careful. I think the default behavior is to pick the parent branch (I'm not sure). I am not aware of anyway to change/pick the default.